# Link class properties to UIControls values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

basicaly I am a C# developer but started learning Objective-C couple of last days.

Now I have to do an exercise which need to create a class and link instance variables (properties) to the `UIControl`s values of the View (e.g. `UITextField` string value).

Meaning I have already implemented the desired `IBOutlet`s in the ViewControler and inside this controler I will create an instance of the created class. In C# a class could implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, bind the class to the controls and notify the object when the `Datasource` value has changed.

Is there anything equal to this concept in Objective C? Or how can I achieve something like that, only through events when value changed for every `Control`?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question but if you're asking about receiving user-initiated events, there are two common ways.  For a simple control, like a button, you define an IBAction method and link it to an event that comes from the button.  For a more-complex control, like a text field, you assign a delegate object and it is notified when specific actions happen.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, I know these concepts, I need for the control to notify the class object instance property when the value is changed and the opposite! In C# you could bind an object to the control and a property to a control's property value.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and grammar is a bit ambiguous but it seems to me what you want is custom (manual) property getters/setters. Try this:

```
@intrface AClass: NSObject {
    int iVar;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int iVar;

@end

@implementation AClass

- (int)iVar
{
    // notify object of value being read, then:
    return iVar;
}

- (void)setIVar:(int)_iVar
{
    iVar = _iVar;
    // then notify object about property being set
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you. I need the control to update AClass.iVar whenever the UITextField value has changed and if programamtically change the AClass.iVar, the UITextField value to change too...

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're asking for from your question.  Are you asking whether the ViewController views can auto-update when your model changes?

There are a bunch of different mechanisms for providing notifications between objects/classes/etc.  The main ones are as follows (I've included IBAction which you probably know for completeness):

1) IBAction - For UI controls just as you've connected IBOutlets in your UIViewController class, you can also fire events (touch up/touch down/etc) on user interaction.

2) NSNotification - you can post these pretty much anywhere:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003701

3) Key-Value Observing:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177i

Comment: I think that one of these 3 solution will give me a solution. Yes I want to auto-update view's controls when model changes and the way around.

Comment: I suggest reading up on them, even if you're not going to use them for this particular task.  For managing a UITextField read up on the use of delegates (which you'll see a lot in objective-c) and in particular the UITextFieldDelegate protocol.

Comment: Ok ofcourse I will, and it's not specific to this Control, I just mention that.